# Postgresql round timestamp to nearest 30 seconds

Tags: sql, postgresql

is possible in postgres to round timestamp to nearest 30 seconds?
For example:

```
source -> result

2017-06-07 14:11:20 -> 2017-06-07 14:11:00
2017-06-07 14:11:40 -> 2017-06-07 14:11:30
2017-06-07 14:12:10 -> 2017-06-07 14:12:00
```

Comment: and `2017-06-07 14:11:50 -> 2017-06-07 14:12:00`?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select (date_trunc('minute', ts) +
        (case when extract(second from ts) > 30 then 30 else 0 end) * interval '1 second' 
       ) as rounded_ts
```

Note:  This rounds 30 second downward.

Answer (score 7):

```
select to_timestamp( round( ( extract ('epoch' from ts) ) /30 ) * 30 )
```

Comment: That shoud be `to_timestamp()` instead of `timestamp()`: `to_timestamp(round( extract('epoch' from ts) / 30 ) * 30)` then it works perfectly. (While the accepted answer doesn't round to the nearest 30 secs.) I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: i guess you should be using floor instead of round

Answer (score 0):

quite ugly to round upwords and downwords:

```
t=# with a(ts) as (
  values ('2017-06-07 14:11:20'::timestamp),('2017-06-07 14:11:40'),('2017-06-07 14:12:10'),('2017-06-07 14:11:50')
)
, c as (
  select *,date_trunc('minute',ts) t0, date_trunc('minute',ts) + '15 seconds'::interval t1,date_trunc('minute',ts)+ '30 seconds'::interval t2,date_trunc('minute',ts)+ '45 seconds'::interval t3, date_trunc('minute',ts) + '1 minute'::interval t5
  from a
)
select case when ts between t0 and t1 then t0 when ts between t1 and t3 then t2 when ts between t3 and t5 then t5 end rnd,ts from c;
         rnd         |         ts
---------------------+---------------------
 2017-06-07 14:11:30 | 2017-06-07 14:11:20
 2017-06-07 14:11:30 | 2017-06-07 14:11:40
 2017-06-07 14:12:00 | 2017-06-07 14:12:10
 2017-06-07 14:12:00 | 2017-06-07 14:11:50
(4 rows)

Time: 0.434 ms
```