# Query to round up timestamp to nearest 10 minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, rounding

I am trying to round up a timestamp to the next full 10 minutes.
I have tried below solutions but wasn't able to get my expected results

- [Postgres: how do you round a timestamp up or down to the nearest minute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195439/postgres-how-do-you-round-a-timestamp-up-or-down-to-the-nearest-minute)
- [Postgresql round timestamp to nearest 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412420/postgresql-round-timestamp-to-nearest-30-seconds)
- [How to round to nearest X minutes with PL/pgSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136415/how-to-round-to-nearest-x-minutes-with-pl-pgsql)

I also tried `date_trunc()`, but couldn't make it work.

Expected results:

| input | expected output |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 10:00:00 | 2023-07-01 10:10:00 |
| 2023-07-01 10:00:01 | 2023-07-01 10:10:00 |
| 2023-07-01 10:01:00 | 2023-07-01 10:10:00 |
| 2023-07-01 10:05:00 | 2023-07-01 10:10:00 |
| 2023-07-01 10:09:59 | 2023-07-01 10:10:00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
select dtime,
       (date_trunc('hour', dtime) +
        (cast(extract(minute from dtime) as int)/10 + 1) * 10 * interval '1 minute' 
       ) as rounded_dtime
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2UK1TJdo)

Comment: Thanks. this solution worked as per my needs

Answer (score 2):

Since **Postgres 14**, there is [`date_bin()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) to **truncate** to the nearest time interval. (Similar to `date_trunc()`, which can only truncate to full units (1 minute, 1 hour, etc.).

```
date_bin('10 min', ts, '2000-1-1')
```

But you want the *ceiling*, not the *floor*.
Your expected output indicates you are satisfied with adding 10 minutes:

```
date_bin('10 min', ts, '2000-1-1') + interval '10 min'
```

Also ~ 5x faster than manual computations.
To truly **round up** (keep exact matches instead of incrementing by 10 minutes):

```
CASE WHEN date_bin('10 min', ts, '2000-1-1') = ts
     THEN ts
     ELSE date_bin('10 min', ts, '2000-1-1') + interval '10 min' END
```

Or shorter and a bit faster, yet (if not as clear):

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(date_bin('10 min', ts, '2000-1-1'), ts) + interval '10 min', ts)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Vmybg7H)

See:

- [What is the fastest way to truncate timestamps to 5 minutes in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299342/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-truncate-timestamps-to-5-minutes-in-postgres/75160734#75160734)

Answer (score 0):

Great question! Postgres does not provide a built-in function to get this exact behavior.

You could, however, accomplish this using date manipulation functions. A query to do that would be:

```sql
SELECT    
     timestamp_value,
    (date_trunc('hour', timestamp_value) +
    CEIL(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM timestamp_value) / 10) * INTERVAL '10 minutes') AS rounded_timestamp_value
FROM timestamps_table;
```

Of course, this query makes a few assumptions:

1. You have a table named `timestamps_table`
2. A field `timestamp_value` stores the timestamps.

Test it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CaJUBgoZ)

Comment: This does not give me the expected results. for e.g, if I give input as '2023-07-01 10:00:00', output is also the same. Whereas I expect value as '2023-07-01 10:10:00'. The solution provided above by SelVazi is working fine