# SQLAlchemy problem with grouping into 30 minutes interval

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

To all the SQL experts out here, I'm trying to write a query to get total energy usage, per 30 minutes, of a day, from the table below.

For more information, kwh stores value sent from a device installed to the power grid, where the device will report the current electric meter at some interval basis. (Only when there's electric flowing, otherwise there will be no data.)

The below is a simplified table.

```
class EnergyLogTable(BaseModel):
__tablename__ = 'energy_log_table'
kwh = db.Column(db.Numeric(scale=2), default=0.0)
created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
```

And this is my current query,

```
date_label = 'hour'

timestamp = func.date_trunc('minute', models.EnergyDispensesLog.created_at)
epoch_seconds = func.extract('epoch', timestamp).label('epoch_seconds')
interval = cast(cast(epoch_seconds, Integer) / 1800, Integer) * 1800

base_query = (
    select(
        func.to_timestamp(interval).label(date_label),
        (func.max(models.EnergyLogTable.kwh) - func.min(models.EnergyLogTable.kwh)).label('energy_spent')
    ).where(
        models.EnergyLogTable.created_at >= from_date,
        models.EnergyLogTable.created_at < to_date,
        models.EnergyLogTable.kwh > 0,
    ).group_by(interval, date_label).order_by(date_label)
)
```

Sample data:

```
created_at                      kwh
"2023-10-25 06:56:18.015066+00" 559.40
"2023-10-25 06:57:15.512495+00" 559.58
"2023-10-25 06:58:15.482616+00" 559.75
"2023-10-25 06:59:15.510724+00" 559.92
"2023-10-25 07:00:15.551606+00" 560.11
"2023-10-25 07:01:15.453912+00" 560.28
"2023-10-25 07:02:15.38114+00"  560.47
"2023-10-25 07:03:15.346221+00" 560.63
"2023-10-25 07:04:15.426906+00" 560.82
"2023-10-25 07:05:15.412163+00" 561.00
"2023-10-25 07:06:15.48954+00"  561.16
"2023-10-25 07:07:15.388114+00" 561.35
"2023-10-25 07:08:15.404986+00" 561.52
"2023-10-25 07:09:15.417893+00" 561.71
"2023-10-25 07:10:15.39941+00"  561.88
"2023-10-25 07:11:15.448669+00" 562.07
"2023-10-25 07:12:15.557211+00" 562.24
"2023-10-25 07:13:15.397659+00" 562.41
"2023-10-25 07:14:15.47744+00"  562.60
"2023-10-25 07:15:15.528852+00" 562.77
"2023-10-25 07:16:15.421955+00" 562.96
"2023-10-25 07:17:15.411252+00" 563.12
"2023-10-25 07:18:15.449404+00" 563.30
"2023-10-25 07:19:15.459984+00" 563.49
"2023-10-25 07:20:15.468558+00" 563.66
"2023-10-25 07:21:15.47227+00"  563.85
"2023-10-25 07:22:15.350083+00" 564.02
"2023-10-25 07:23:15.644026+00" 564.20
"2023-10-25 07:24:15.454081+00" 564.37
"2023-10-25 07:25:15.43371+00"  564.55
"2023-10-25 07:26:15.573115+00" 564.74
"2023-10-25 07:27:15.557926+00" 564.91
"2023-10-25 07:28:15.43053+00"  565.09
"2023-10-25 07:29:15.558076+00" 565.27
"2023-10-25 07:30:15.419831+00" 565.45
"2023-10-25 07:31:15.548472+00" 565.62
"2023-10-25 07:32:15.498099+00" 565.80
"2023-10-25 07:33:15.332133+00" 565.99
"2023-10-25 07:34:15.463259+00" 566.16
"2023-10-25 07:35:15.491288+00" 566.35
"2023-10-25 07:36:15.485671+00" 566.51
"2023-10-25 07:37:15.395341+00" 566.70
"2023-10-25 07:38:15.401426+00" 566.87
"2023-10-25 07:39:15.414545+00" 567.05
"2023-10-25 07:40:15.436152+00" 567.24
"2023-10-25 07:41:15.38887+00"  567.40
"2023-10-25 07:42:15.484769+00" 567.60
"2023-10-25 07:43:15.484849+00" 567.76
"2023-10-25 07:44:15.448255+00" 567.95
"2023-10-25 07:45:15.507435+00" 568.12
"2023-10-25 07:46:15.450651+00" 568.30
"2023-10-25 07:47:15.418091+00" 568.49
"2023-10-25 07:48:15.320837+00" 568.66
"2023-10-25 07:49:15.388797+00" 568.84
"2023-10-25 07:50:15.571942+00" 569.01
"2023-10-25 07:51:15.324393+00" 569.20
"2023-10-25 07:52:15.321933+00" 569.37
"2023-10-25 07:53:15.515515+00" 569.54
"2023-10-25 07:54:15.546828+00" 569.73
"2023-10-25 07:55:15.518291+00" 569.90
"2023-10-25 07:56:15.522586+00" 570.09
"2023-10-25 07:57:15.537949+00" 570.26
"2023-10-25 07:58:15.401685+00" 570.44
"2023-10-25 07:59:15.335498+00" 570.62
"2023-10-25 08:00:11.204091+00" 570.76
```

The query seems working until when there's meter flowing in between for example, xx:59 and xx:01 marks.

Which for the 06:30 to 07:00 span, it uses the highest value 559.92 to subtract the lowest value 559.40, resulting 0.52 kWh.

The next span of 07:00 to 07:30, it uses 565.27-560.11=5.16, etc...

So energy used in between xx:59 to xx:01, or between xx:29 to xx:31 are not being included into the calculation.

I'm seeking for help if there's possibility that I can get the first value of the next span to do the math? For instance for the 06:30 to 07:00 span, we do 560.11-559.40 instead of 559.92-559.40. It will be appreciated if there's even better approach or solutions toward this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44412495/11612918) would work better? (adapted to minutes instead of seconds)

Comment: @M.O Not exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm trying [this](https://learnsql.com/blog/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql) approach which seems to be the solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably even better, using a lead/lag first to generate the differences, and then grouping those into buckets.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, for simply reproduce I would use postgresql query base on your SQLAlchemy query. Your desired output is needed to use lead function after groupby, the lead value is nextMinKwh, if nextMinKwh is null which means this is latest value so far.

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN nextMinKwh IS NOT NULL THEN nextMinKwh - minKwh 
        ELSE maxKwh - minKwh 
    END AS payKwh 
FROM (
    SELECT
        to_timestamp(interval) AS date_label,
        max(kwh) AS maxKwh,
        min(kwh) AS minKwh,
        sum(kwh) AS sumKwh,
        min(created_at) AS minTime,
        max(created_at) AS maxTime,
        lead(min(kwh)) OVER (ORDER BY interval) AS nextMinKwh
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            kwh, 
            created_at,
            extract('epoch' FROM date_trunc('minute', created_at))::integer AS epoch_seconds,
            (extract('epoch' FROM date_trunc('minute', created_at))::integer / 1800)::integer * 1800 AS interval
        FROM energylogtable
    ) AS t1
    GROUP BY date_label, interval
    ORDER BY date_label
) t2;
```

data

```
create table EnergyLogTable(
    id serial primary key,
    Created_At timestamp,
    Kwh float
);


insert into EnergyLogTable(Created_At, Kwh) values 
('2023-10-25 06:56:18.015066', 559.40),
('2023-10-25 06:57:15.512495', 559.58),
('2023-10-25 06:58:15.482616',559.75),
('2023-10-25 06:59:15.510724',559.92),
('2023-10-25 07:00:15.551606',560.11),
('2023-10-25 07:01:15.453912',560.28),
('2023-10-25 07:02:15.38114', 560.47),
('2023-10-25 07:03:15.346221',560.63),
('2023-10-25 07:04:15.426906',560.82),
('2023-10-25 07:05:15.412163',561.00),
('2023-10-25 07:06:15.48954', 561.16),
('2023-10-25 07:07:15.388114',561.35),
('2023-10-25 07:08:15.404986',561.52),
('2023-10-25 07:09:15.417893',561.71),
('2023-10-25 07:10:15.39941', 561.88),
('2023-10-25 07:11:15.448669',562.07),
('2023-10-25 07:12:15.557211',562.24),
('2023-10-25 07:13:15.397659',562.41),
('2023-10-25 07:14:15.47744', 562.60),
('2023-10-25 07:15:15.528852',562.77),
('2023-10-25 07:16:15.421955',562.96),
('2023-10-25 07:17:15.411252',563.12),
('2023-10-25 07:18:15.449404',563.30),
('2023-10-25 07:19:15.459984',563.49),
('2023-10-25 07:20:15.468558',563.66),
('2023-10-25 07:21:15.47227', 563.85),
('2023-10-25 07:22:15.350083',564.02),
('2023-10-25 07:23:15.644026',564.20),
('2023-10-25 07:24:15.454081',564.37),
('2023-10-25 07:25:15.43371', 564.55),
('2023-10-25 07:26:15.573115',564.74),
('2023-10-25 07:27:15.557926',564.91),
('2023-10-25 07:28:15.43053', 565.09),
('2023-10-25 07:29:15.558076',565.27),
('2023-10-25 07:30:15.419831',565.45),
('2023-10-25 07:31:15.548472',565.62),
('2023-10-25 07:32:15.498099',565.80),
('2023-10-25 07:33:15.332133',565.99),
('2023-10-25 07:34:15.463259',566.16),
('2023-10-25 07:35:15.491288',566.35),
('2023-10-25 07:36:15.485671',566.51),
('2023-10-25 07:37:15.395341',566.70),
('2023-10-25 07:38:15.401426',566.87),
('2023-10-25 07:39:15.414545',567.05),
('2023-10-25 07:40:15.436152',567.24),
('2023-10-25 07:41:15.38887', 567.40),
('2023-10-25 07:42:15.484769',567.60),
('2023-10-25 07:43:15.484849',567.76),
('2023-10-25 07:44:15.448255',567.95),
('2023-10-25 07:45:15.507435',568.12),
('2023-10-25 07:46:15.450651',568.30),
('2023-10-25 07:47:15.418091',568.49),
('2023-10-25 07:48:15.320837',568.66),
('2023-10-25 07:49:15.388797',568.84),
('2023-10-25 07:50:15.571942',569.01),
('2023-10-25 07:51:15.324393',569.20),
('2023-10-25 07:52:15.321933',569.37),
('2023-10-25 07:53:15.515515',569.54),
('2023-10-25 07:54:15.546828',569.73),
('2023-10-25 07:55:15.518291',569.90),
('2023-10-25 07:56:15.522586',570.09),
('2023-10-25 07:57:15.537949',570.26),
('2023-10-25 07:58:15.401685',570.44),
('2023-10-25 07:59:15.335498',570.62),
('2023-10-25 08:00:11.204091',570.76),
('2023-10-26 07:58:15.335498',571.62),
('2023-10-26 08:10:11.204091',572.76),
('2023-10-27 06:19:15.335498',573.62),
('2023-10-27 06:58:11.204091',574.76)
```

Result

| date_label | maxkwh | minkwh | sumkwh | mintime | maxtime | nextminkwh | paykwh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-25T06:30:00+00:00 | 559.92 | 559.4 | 2238.65 | 2023-10-25T06:56:18.015066 | 2023-10-25T06:59:15.510724 | 560.11 | 0.7100000000000364 |
| 2023-10-25T07:00:00+00:00 | 565.27 | 560.11 | 16880.55 | 2023-10-25T07:00:15.551606 | 2023-10-25T07:29:15.558076 | 565.45 | 5.340000000000032 |
| 2023-10-25T07:30:00+00:00 | 570.62 | 565.45 | 17041.02 | 2023-10-25T07:30:15.419831 | 2023-10-25T07:59:15.335498 | 570.76 | 5.309999999999945 |
| 2023-10-25T08:00:00+00:00 | 570.76 | 570.76 | 570.76 | 2023-10-25T08:00:11.204091 | 2023-10-25T08:00:11.204091 | 571.62 | 0.8600000000000136 |
| 2023-10-26T07:30:00+00:00 | 571.62 | 571.62 | 571.62 | 2023-10-26T07:58:15.335498 | 2023-10-26T07:58:15.335498 | 572.76 | 1.1399999999999864 |
| 2023-10-26T08:00:00+00:00 | 572.76 | 572.76 | 572.76 | 2023-10-26T08:10:11.204091 | 2023-10-26T08:10:11.204091 | 573.62 | 0.8600000000000136 |
| 2023-10-27T06:00:00+00:00 | 573.62 | 573.62 | 573.62 | 2023-10-27T06:19:15.335498 | 2023-10-27T06:19:15.335498 | 574.76 | 1.1399999999999864 |
| 2023-10-27T06:30:00+00:00 | 574.76 | 574.76 | 574.76 | 2023-10-27T06:58:11.204091 | 2023-10-27T06:58:11.204091 | NULL | 0.0 |